# How to find the distance(physical in m and pixels) between two object(points) in image in OpenCV and C+++?

Tags: c++, opencv, euclidean-distance

Im using OpenCV and C++. I have already done the code where can find the center of the object. I also have the prior information about the distance between the camera and object(s) in the image.
I need to compute the distance (real physical one in m or cm, and also the one in pixels) between two objects in the image, or between the two centers of those objects).

Here is the code to find the center moment of rectangle object. Similar approach  would be to find the center of other shape (object).

```
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

           Mat image = imread("000167.png");
           Mat gray,bw,dil,erd, dst_final;
       Mat new_src=image.clone();

     for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++ )
    {
       for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++ )
       {
              for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
              {
                     new_src.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c]= saturate_cast<uchar>( 1.5*(image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] ));

              }
       }
     }


      cv::GaussianBlur(new_src, src_gray, cv::Size(3,3),1,1,BORDER_DEFAULT); //original
      medianBlur(new_src, src_gray, 11);
      blur( new_src, src_gray, Size(3,3) );
      cvtColor(src_gray,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
      Canny(gray,bw,600,1200,5,true);
                    Mat grad,bw1;
                    Mat morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(20,10));
                    morphologyEx(bw, grad, MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);        
                    threshold(grad, bw1, 255.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);                

          vector<vector<Point> > contours;
      vector<vector<Point> > rough;
      vector<vector<Point> >rough_color;
      vector<vector<Point> >precise;
          vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
      Mat dst = image.clone();
          findContours(bw1.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

      vector<Point> approx;

      for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {

           approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true) * 0.01, true);
           if (fabs(contourArea(approx)) <2000 || fabs(contourArea(approx))>50000)                                     
               continue;

                  Rect r = boundingRect(contours[i]);
                  if( (float) (r.height/r.width) > 1.5 && (float) (r.height/r.width) <3)
                  {
                   rough.push_back(approx);
                   }
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < rough.size(); i++)
      {
          Rect bound=boundingRect(rough[i]);
          Rect x, y, w, h = boundingRect(rough[i]);
          rectangle(dst,Point(bound.br().x,bound.br().y), Point(bound.tl().x,bound.tl().y),Scalar(255, 0, 0),2);
          RotatedRect rectPoint = minAreaRect(rough[i]);

              Point2f fourPoint2f_rough[4];
              rectPoint.points(fourPoint2f_rough);
          vector<Point> fourPoint_rough;
          for(int i = 0; i <4; i++)
         {
             fourPoint_rough.push_back(fourPoint2f_rough[i]);
         }


        {
            line(dst, fourPoint2f_rough[i], fourPoint2f_rough[i + 1], Scalar(255,0,0), 3);
        }
        line(dst, fourPoint2f_rough[0], fourPoint2f_rough[3], Scalar(255,0,0), 3); */
      }

      if(rough.size() !=0 )
      {
      for( int i = 0; i< rough.size(); i++ )
      {
          vector<Moments> mu(1);
          vector<Point2f> mc(1);
          int gray_level;
          // compute the central momment
             mu[0] = moments( rough[i], false );
             mc[0] = Point2f( mu[0].m10/mu[0].m00 , mu[0].m01/mu[0].m00 );
          circle( dst, mc[0], 4, Scalar(0,0,255), -1, 8, 0 );
          gray_level=gray.at<uchar>(mc[0]);
          if(gray_level<200 && gray_level>20)
          {rough_color.push_back(rough[i]);}
      }


      for(int i = 0; i < rough_color.size(); i++)
      {
          Rect bound=boundingRect(rough_color[i]);
          Rect x, y, w, h = boundingRect(rough_color[i]);
          RotatedRect rectPoint = minAreaRect(rough_color[i]);
              Point2f fourPoint2f_color[4];
              rectPoint.points(fourPoint2f_color);
         vector<Point> fourPoint_color;
         for(int i = 0; i <4; i++)
         {
             fourPoint_color.push_back(fourPoint2f_color[i]);
         }


         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            line(dst, fourPoint2f_color[i], fourPoint2f_color[i + 1], Scalar(0,255,0), 3);
        }
        line(dst, fourPoint2f_color[0], fourPoint2f_color[3], Scalar(0,255,0), 3);
      }

      }
...
```

So just need a code to get the distance (real in cm or m and the one in pixels) between those two center moments(two centers of the objects in the image). I include the outcome image of the center on the rectangle window (red dot in the window). So in this case I would like to compute the distance between the window and the "OPEN" box sign.

[image: Center of rectangular window]

Comment: Unclear. What is the relationship between the code you posted and the task you aim to do ? You are asking for both metric and pixel distance. For the latter, isn't it kind of obvious if you have the coordinates of the centers? For the metric distance, this is theorically impossible with one camera, unless you know the distance between the camera and the objects. Could you maybe edit question and clarify ?

Comment: OK. Code is to find the center of the object. In this case is that airplane door window. Clear? Ok yes if have the pixels coordinate of the two centers than its easy. Im my question I pointed out that already know the distance between the camera and the object. I said I have the distance between the camera an the object, I know that information prior, cause can measure that distance with a laser.

Comment: Is it clear now?So basically, just need to find the metric distance, knowing the  distance between the camera and the objects. OK?

Comment: Still unclear to me: why don't you proceed similarly to get the bounding rectangle of the "open" sign, then just check the distance between the two rectangles ? Or if you have trouble locating it, you could search for the white color in the image? Tip: aside from posting the code, you should describe in a few lines the algorithm your are implementing, that would help answering your question.

Comment: I dont have problem get the bounding rectangle of the "open" sign. Also not any problem locate it. Only didnt enclose the code. My problem is not that. My problem is to get the metric (real physical distance) between the  "open" sign and the door window. And once again I know the distance between the camera and the objects. Is it clear now???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is about getting the metric distance between two points.

If:

- the two points are on a (geometrical) plane that is perpendicular to the optical axis of the camera
- you have the distance between the camera center and the plane

then the metric distance between these two points can be computed by using the projection basics:

- d_m: metric distance between the two points (m.)
- d_p: pixel distance between the two points
- f: focal (m.)
- k: nbe of pixels per meter of the camera sensor (=1/ps , ps:pixel size, ususally 5 to 10 um)
- z_M: distance between the two points (m.)

We have: `d_p = k . f . d_M/Z_M`

so:  `d_M = d_p . z_M / (k.f)`

If the above conditions are not perfectly met, it will induce some error. It is unclear from the question if these requirements are fulfilled. If they are not, then it could be impossible to get an answer. Unless maybe the angle between the plane and the axis is known, in which case some basic trigonometry calculation will be required.

Comment: Yes, I understand